# Firebase Cloud Messaging Error: "Service messaging is not available"

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following the guide to setup a javascript client app (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?authuser=0#web-modular-api) and I have the firebase npm package with version 9.23.0 installed in my project.

But when starting my app over localhost (I tried over http and https, but the result is the same), the line `const messaging = getMessaging(app);` throws the error: "Service messaging is not available".

Before that I created a pretty basic project and application in the firebase console and activated the Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) and as well as generated a new key pair.

Am I missing something for the code to work?